# Facebook Like To Download

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Iam trying to develop a application which let people to download a freebie only if they have liked my fan page.For now I am using this code to trigger the like button click event

```
 FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',function(response) {

      download();// this makes a aaax call to get the download file
});
```

But for the persons who have already liked my facebook page , how to detect and give the freebie? Is there any possible fql query to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FB.api("me/likes/page", function(response) 
{
          if ( response.data.length == 1 ) 
         { 
            //has liked

         } else 
         {

             //Not liked
}});
```

Source and download script -http://www.webtuts.info/webdevelopment/facebook-download-script-2/225/